# Controlling space between sentences in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

In Microsoft Word, if I use two spaces between sentences, the spacing becomes way more than twice the distance if I use only one space.  This happens only in a particular document, and does not occur if I copy-paste the text into a new document.  Doing regular paste and paste as plain text produces the same result.

This is with left-justified text, Times New Roman 12.  All settings in Font and Paragraph are the same between the documents.  This is in Microsoft Word 2016.  No compatibility settings are enabled.

If I only use one space between sentences, the behavior is as expected.

Here is a picture showing the issue I'm talking about.

[image: Excessive inter-sentence spacing]

**What setting controls this behavior and how can I change my document so that the formatting matches what happens in a new document?**

- Link to this document: [Original document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BZOdHX113RB87ftcAABrcPP1YnVWXZ-i)
- Link to new document with same text: [New document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZdR_Dcc_jzJ-7x_I6lQSIN99da86SVIs)

Comment: Please post this document for analysis.

Comment: note that [it's a bad idea to end a sentence with 2 spaces](https://slate.com/technology/2011/01/two-spaces-after-a-period-why-you-should-never-ever-do-it.html). It only makes the sentence more readable in [monospaced texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (like in typewriters) but for proportional fonts it doesn't make a difference. In fact the *smart cut and paste* option of Word and other document editors will always insert a single space after sentences. And in webpages multiple spaces will be contracted to a single one

Comment: the modern style is to use zero space where the punctuation should be attached to, and a single space on the other side. [*"From around 1950, single sentence spacing became standard in books, magazines, and newspapers"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing#cite_note-10)

Comment: The question is not how many spaces to add after a period. The question is why the two documents with identical text format differently, and what setting controls that.

Comment: @devtk: The question is about one specific document, but without having access to it we cannot do anything. If you are worried about exposing its contents, post a copy with just enough text to show the problem, and delete the rest.

Comment: @harrymc, That's a fair point. It's a business document and I'm not sure how to remove all metadata from it. I know some things remain stored even after you delete. I will look into it.  Was hoping someone may know the setting without it, but it doesn't seem like that's happening.

Comment: [How to Remove Metadata from Microsoft Word Files](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-remove-metadata-from-microsoft-word-files.cfm).

Comment: @harrymc, Files are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This document seems to have come from another operating system and another
word processor. It refers to fonts that do not exist in Windows, so Word
tries to substitute them with existing fonts, but apparently not very correctly.

I have managed to get rid of the weird formatting, but it took some manipulations.
I did as follows:

- Open menu *File > Options > Advanced*
- Under "Show document content", click *Font Substitution...*, which looks like:

  [image]
- For "Helvetica", set "Substituted font:" to "Arial", click
  *Convert Permanently...* and answer OK
- Click again *Font Substitution...*
- For "Times", set "Substituted font:" to "Times New Roman",
  click *Convert Permanently...* and answer OK
- Open menu *File > Save As*, choose your folder, set "Save as type:" to
  "Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)" and save the document
- Close Word
- Open the `.doc` document - the spacing should now be normal.

In my testing, all the above steps were necessary and none of them
could be omitted.

Comment: On my system, if I simply saved as Word 97-2003, then loaded that document, it corrected the behavior.  However, on loading, only the "Inherited -> Calibri" font substitution was listed.  The other two disappeared.  What a bizarre bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this exact issue. Try this:

1. Go to "File" tab in MS Word on far left of the screen. Scroll down and select "Options".
2. A new window will open. Select "Advanced" from the menu on the left.
3. Scroll to the bottom of the list of sections. You will see a section titled "Layout options for [DOC TITLE].   Look for the checkbox option titled "Balance SBCS characters and DBCS characters (4th from the top).
4. Select "Okay" to exit out of the "Options" window and go back to your document.

This worked for me. Hope it works for you.